# Stericson's root tools library not working - makes force close?

Tags: android

I am currently testing the roottools jar/library made by stericson in an app, but every time the app loads it force closes.

Here is the code:

```
package com.liamwli.root;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.Toast;

import com.stericson.RootTools.*;

public class root_test extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (RootTools.isBusyboxAvailable()) {
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
        } else {
            RootTools.offerBusyBox(this);
        }

        if (RootTools.isRootAvailable()) {
            Toast liam = Toast.makeText(this, "Root Available",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            liam.show();
        } else {
            // do something else
        }

    }
}
```

And here is the logcat:

```
04-04 21:44:47.009: I/Process(6622): Sending signal. PID: 6622 SIG: 9
04-04 21:45:40.859: I/dalvikvm(6722): Could not find method com.stericson.RootTools.RootTools.isBusyboxAvailable, referenced from method com.liamwli.root.root_test.onCreate
04-04 21:45:40.859: W/dalvikvm(6722): VFY: unable to resolve static method 16: Lcom/stericson/RootTools/RootTools;.isBusyboxAvailable ()Z
04-04 21:45:40.859: D/dalvikvm(6722): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0003
04-04 21:45:40.859: D/AndroidRuntime(6722): Shutting down VM
04-04 21:45:40.859: W/dalvikvm(6722): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ac21f8)
04-04 21:45:40.869: E/AndroidRuntime(6722): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 21:45:40.869: E/AndroidRuntime(6722): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.stericson.RootTools.RootTools
04-04 21:45:40.869: E/AndroidRuntime(6722):     at com.liamwli.root.root_test.onCreate(root_test.java:16)
04-04 21:45:40.869: E/AndroidRuntime(6722):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
04-04 21:45:40.869: E/AndroidRuntime(6722):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
04-04 21:45:40.869: E/AndroidRuntime(6722):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
04-04 21:45:40.869: E/AndroidRuntime(6722):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
04-04 21:45:40.869: E/AndroidRuntime(6722):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-04 21:45:40.869: E/AndroidRuntime(6722):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
04-04 21:45:40.869: E/AndroidRuntime(6722):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-04 21:45:40.869: E/AndroidRuntime(6722):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-04 21:45:40.869: E/AndroidRuntime(6722):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-04 21:45:40.869: E/AndroidRuntime(6722):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 21:45:40.869: E/AndroidRuntime(6722):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-04 21:45:40.869: E/AndroidRuntime(6722):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
04-04 21:45:40.869: E/AndroidRuntime(6722):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
04-04 21:45:40.869: E/AndroidRuntime(6722):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am quite new to android, and I am now very confused :(

If someone could possibly help me, I would be grateful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eclipse, right click your project, navigate to "Build Path", then to "configure build path"
Now choose "add External Jar"
Navigate to the RootTools .jar file you download and choose it.
**Navigate to "Order and Export" make sure the box is ticked next to the library, and move it to the top of the list.**
Finish up by choosing "ok"

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this by separating the imports. Instead of:

```
import com.stericson.RootTools.*;
```

I only used/needed:

```
import com.stericson.RootTools.RootTools;
```

Try adding the others individually if you need them.

```
import com.stericson.RootTools.Mount;
import com.stericson.RootTools.Permissions;
import com.stericson.RootTools.RootToolsException;
import com.stericson.RootTools.Symlink;
import com.stericson.RootTools.SanityCheckRootTools;
```

It worked for me, hope it does for you!

Comment: Nope, this didn't work. But stericson told us how to fix it on the site.